# What's the relationship between csrfmiddlewaretoken and csrftoken?

Tags: django, csrf

I was working with Django to create a website and got some questions about CSRF. I use `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` and add `<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}` in my POST form.

And when I test the website:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 123.207.137.168:8000
```

Then, I got cookies

```
Set-Cookie:csrftoken=Ev8veOH89vFDnG3a0GJUsMXA1oGZXxqXRw2nFWiKrvZ9UE10niTlZCiOxdnoKfTv; expires=Thu, 27-Dec-2018 06:37:41 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
```

But in the html:

```
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='JswHLk4fNpxHkh0OObD1uKiOxSDUzkMDWtqzcsFR5pRdRfYEbNNs1AD23Hkjm2fb' />
```

So I was wondering why the `csrftoken` and `csrfmiddlewaretoken` is different and how did the server use these two value to valid if the request is from the users or hackers?

---

Answer (score 24):

There are some answers in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#how-it-works), but [looking at the code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/middleware/csrf.py) really solves this "mystery"
Basically what django does is the following:

1. Craft a random CSRF secret key
2. Create a random mask string (previously incorrectly [called "salt"](https://groups.google.com/g/django-developers/c/SokWmLcIkds)). Using the mask string, mask (it's not a proper encryption hence the name "mask") the secret key and set the masked result as a CSRF cookie named **csrftoken** (after [version 4.1](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32800) this step is skipped and the **csrftoken** will **NOT** be masked)
3. When user opens a form/request/anything, check if the user has the CSRF cookie set (if they don't have it, craft it as above). If they have it, fetch it, unmask it and get the real secret, re-mask it (with another random mask string) and use this as another token (**csrfmiddlewaretoken**).

Now when you make a POST request for example, the following happens

1. You send the **csrfmiddlewaretoken**
2. Django unmasks the csrf cookie (**csrftoken**) (after [version 4.1](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32800) csrf cookie is not masked so it just gets the value)
3. Django unmasks the token you sent (**csrfmiddlewaretoken**)
4. Django compares them. If the two match, you're ok.

This method with the two tokens is called **Double-Submit Cookie**. Django's way with the masking allows to keep the same csrf secret for some time without having to renew the key for every request

Comment: That was the good answer I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks, you made it so clear and easy to understand! +1

Comment: thanks @John where `CSRF cookie (**csrftoken**)` and `token (**csrfmiddlewaretoken**)` are saved ? in the user browser or in database ? if in the database in which tables ?

Comment: @EllaBlackledge I understand that the 2 of them are generated for each user, how django distingwitch between different users? By ip adress for example ?

Comment: thanks, @John.
one thing, "mask" and "unmask" are more correct terms instead salt.
It was fixed on - https://github.com/django/django/pull/12479

Comment: @ramganesh I updated the terms and added an update on the upcoming (4.1+ versions as well where the cookie is no longer masked). Hope it's clear